# bootstrap Tree View is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap Tree View. I wrote the code according to the documentation, but there is nothing showing up when I open it from a browser. What is wrong?

I extracted `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` from the zip source code and put them into `treeview`.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Treeview -->
<script src="/treeview/bootstrap-treeview.min.css"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
hello
<div class="container">
    <div id="tree"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    var mytree = [
        {
            text: "Parent 1",
            nodes: [
                {
                    text: "Child 1",
                    nodes: [
                        {
                            text: "Grandchild 1"
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Grandchild 2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: "Child 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: "Parent 2"
        }
    ];

    $('#tree').treeview({data: mytree});
</script>
<!-- Font -->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c1d4b38cd6.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- UI -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Treeview -->
<script src="/treeview/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving all your imports to the top? Do you have any errors on your console?

Comment: $('#tree').treeview({data: mytree}); call it only after all script are loaded, so after
<script src="/treeview/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move your treeview init come after the bootstrap-treeview.min.js include, and keep it inside the:

```
$(function(){
    // This code runs after the document ready.
});
```

So it should be:

```
.
.
.
<!-- Treeview -->
<script src="/treeview/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var mytree = [
            {
                text: "Parent 1",
                nodes: [
                    {
                        text: "Child 1",
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                text: "Grandchild 1"
                            },
                            {
                                text: "Grandchild 2"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Child 2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: "Parent 2"
            }
        ];

        $('#tree').treeview({data: mytree});
    });
</script>
```

This is the version that works: https://jsfiddle.net/jc788d2L/

Answer (score 1):

put those links inside your head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/treeview/bootstrap-treeview.min.css"></script>
```

then init the treeview by:

```
$(function(){ 
  $('#tree').treeview({data: mytree});     
})
```

I just wrote an example for you
https://jsbin.com/murerucodo/edit?html,output

You could check it out  :)